# Codeigniter 3 with get_instance(); in hook file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a class in hook folder like this

```
class CheckAuth {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = get_instance();
    }
    public function check()
    {
        $router =& load_class('Router', 'core');
        // $controller = $this->CI->router->class;
        $controller = $router->fetch_class();
        $method     = $router->fetch_method();

        if($controller!='auth')
        {
            echo $this->CI->userdata('admin_id');
        }
    }
}
```

I show error when I get a session

> Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object $this->CI return null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work.

```
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function check()
    {
        $this->CI = get_instance();

        $router =& load_class('Router', 'core');
        // $controller = $this->CI->router->class;
        $controller = $router->fetch_class();
        $method     = $router->fetch_method();

        if($controller!='auth')
        {
            echo $this->CI->userdata('admin_id');
        }
    }
```

Comment: $this->CI = get_instance(); is not necessary.  $router =& load_class('Router', 'core'); is enough. But it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because CI isn't loaded yet in some hooks points (pre_controller, pre_system). You are probably trying to load class in some of these.